# Using the Divergence theorem to show that a graph has least area among all surfaces with the same boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

$\DeclareMathOperator{\graph}{graph}$I want to show that for $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ an open bounded regular domain with a $C^2$ function $u:\overline{\Omega}\to\mathbb{R}$ that the graph $\graph(u):=\{(x,y,u(x,y))\,:\,(x,y)\in\overline{\Omega}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ of $u$ is minimal and satisfies the following inequality:
*For $\Sigma\subset \Omega\times\mathbb{R}$ a compact surface with $\partial\Sigma=\partial\graph(u)$ the divergence theorem (on suitable domains) yields*
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\area}{area}
\area(\graph(u))\leq \area(\Sigma).
$$

What I have thought of so far is the following: If $\Sigma$ and $\graph(u)$ partially intersect apart from their boundary, the application could become more complicated. To avoid this, consider the following:

We can apply the divergence theorem on the connected component of $\Omega \times [-M,\infty) \backslash \graph(u)$ containing $\Omega \times \{-M\}$, where $M$ is sufficiently large such that $\graph(u)$ and $\Sigma$ are contained in $\Omega \times [-M,\infty).$
Then we apply again the divergence theorem but in the connected component of $\Omega \times [-M,\infty) \backslash \Sigma$ containing $\Omega \times \{-M\}$.

My problem consists of how to apply the divergence theorem here exactly since we did not cover it in the lectures. Could anyone help me on how to apply it to show the desired property?

Comment: I would suggest looking for a $2$-form $\omega$ on $\Omega\times\Bbb R$ with the properties that (i) $d\omega=0$ (because of the hypothesis on $u$ you forgot to tell us), (ii) $\omega$ restricts to the graph of $u$ (or any parallel translate thereof) to be the area $2$-form, and (iii) $\omega$ restricts to any other surface to be greater than or equal to its area $2$-form.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the graph is minimal, I'll add it in the description. So taking $\omega=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\partial_xu^2+\partial_yu^2}}(-\partial_xu\text{d}y\wedge\text{d}z-\partial_yu\text{d}z\wedge\text{d}x+\text{d}x\wedge\text{d}y)$ would yield $d\omega=0$ and I would get $$0=\int_{graph(u)}div(N)dvol=\int_{graph(u)}dw=\int_{\partial graph(u)}\langle N,N\rangle dA=\bigg\vert\int_{\partial\Sigma}\langle N,n\rangle dA\bigg\vert\leq\int_{\partial \Sigma}\vert\langle N,n\rangle\vert dA\leq area(\Sigma)$$ where $n$ is normal to $\Sigma$. Would that work?